# maven picking up environment variable set by jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using the following maven pom.xml snippet to read a property called BUILD_NUMBER from a file jenkins/version.properties.

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                     <phase>initialize</phase>
                     <goals>
                         <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                         <files>
                             <file>${project.parent.basedir}/jenkins/version.properties</file>
                         </files>
                     </configuration>
                 </execution>
             </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Jenkins also has an environment variable called $BUILD_NUMBER. I have child pom.xmls which try and use the $BUILD_NUMBER, and it keeps picking up the Jenkins environment variable value for $BUILD_NUMBER instead of the one from jenkins/version.properties. I am just wondering if maven puts values it reads from files into the environment? If so, it looks as though Jenkins is over writing this value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the BUILD_NUMBER variable to a different name so that it didn't clash with the Jenkins $BUILD_NUMBER environment variable. That seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for the help - set me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think `${project.parent.basedir}` evaluates to anything useful?

I'd say your `<file>` points to a non-existing file, so the `properties-maven-plugin` does not read any properties, so `BUILD_NUMBER` is not defined as a property, and `${BUILD_NUMBER}` falls back to `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`, which is your Jenkins environment variable.

Comment: ${project.parent.basedir} does evaluate correctly. I have checked it.