# Using a jenkins plugin to get the artifacts involved in maven build

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to the jenkins world and I know this question seems somewhat open-ended, but after reading the jenkins plugin development tutorial I'm still lost as to where to start.
I need to write a jenkins plugin that can determine the maven dependencies used in the project.

I'm very confused about which jenkins @Extension I should be extending or what hudson class I should be investigating to get the maven artifacts.

Currently, I have a class that extends hudson.tasks.Recorder and I'm implementing the perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) method. But I'm not sure how to extract the artifacts from (presumably) the AbstractBuild object.

Any direction would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

This SO question is similar but it has no answers yet.

[Get Maven artifact properties from Jenkins plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26885175/get-maven-artifact-properties-from-jenkins-plugin)

Comment: What is the purpose of the maven dependencies which used in the project? Why do you need them in Jenkins ?

Comment: It's for reporting purposes. I need the groupId, artifactId, version, and I need to push this to our application server.

Comment: Why not pulling the information via REST API from jenkins ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this REST API approach. Can you point me to it please?